# VBA code Error in creating too many worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub MergeExcelFiles()
Dim fnameList, fnameCurFile As Variant
Dim countFiles, countSheets As Integer
Dim wksCurSheet As Worksheet
Dim wbkCurBook, wbkSrcBook As Workbook
Dim a As Long

fnameList = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", Title:="Choose Excel files to merge", MultiSelect:=True)

If (vbBoolean <> VarType(fnameList)) Then

    If (UBound(fnameList) > 0) Then
        countFiles = 0
        countSheets = 0

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        Set wbkCurBook = ActiveWorkbook

        For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
            countFiles = countFiles + 1

            Set wbkSrcBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fnameCurFile)

            For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
                countSheets = countSheets + 1
                wksCurSheet.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
            Next

            wbkSrcBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

        Next

        Dim NowTic As Long
        Dim EndToc As Long

        EndToc = (10 * 1000)

        Do
            NowTic = NowTic + 1
            DoEvents
        Loop Until NowTic >= EndToc

        If Sheets.Count = 2 Then
            Sheets(1).Name = "EL"
            Sheets(2).Name = "WL"
        ElseIf Sheets.Count = 3 Then
            Sheets(1).Name = "EL"
            If InStr(1, fnameList(1), "_FM_") > 0 Then
                Sheets(2).Name = "FM"
            ElseIf InStr(1, fnameList(1), "_NL_") > 0 Then
                Sheets(2).Name = "NL"
            End If
            Sheets(3).Name = "WL"
        ElseIf Sheets.Count = 4 Then
            Sheets(1).Name = "EL"
            Sheets(2).Name = "FM"
            Sheets(3).Name = "NL"
            Sheets(4).Name = "WL"
        End If

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

        MsgBox "Processed " & countFiles & " files" & vbCrLf & "Merged " & countSheets & " worksheets", Title:="Merge Excel files"
    End If

Else
    MsgBox "No files selected", Title:="Merge Excel files"
End If
```

End Sub

My code keeps producing more worksheets than needed. How do I get it to stop? It only does it when I try to have 3 workbooks total. I've tried adding a TicToc to the code as you can see above but that hasn't helped. I don't know what else to try.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AvkL.png

Comment: I am not sure what is the problem that you are experiencing. I ran your code and works fine on my end. The only thing I found somewhat odd is that you are renaming the first four sheets, but if you are merging four files that have more than one sheet each, then you will have more than four sheets so none will be renamed. Can you specify more precisely what happens when you run your code?

Comment: Also, referencing the .png you added, is it possible that three of the files you are trying to merge all contain a sheet called "Table 1"?

Comment: The issue I'm having is that I only want it to add the names of the file (EL, FM, NL, WL) but it adds the table(1), table(2),... I don't want it adding the table names to the worksheet. basically I want table(1),table(2),... so on to be named EL, FM, NL, depending on the file name. It creates double the worksheets I just want one set that's named EL, FM,...

Comment: The if block to rename sheets only contemplates renaming sheets if the workbook has 2, 3, or 4 sheets. It will not rename anything otherwise. Given that the book where you have the macro must have one sheet (at least), it will only kick in if you only consolidate three files (which will end up with a 4-sheet book). There is no way that your macro can rename any sheet if you end up with more than 4 sheets (i.e. if you try to consolidate more than three files, providing you only have one sheet to start with in your macro book).

Comment: My guess is that you ran the macro once with three files and got the result you wanted, but then you ran it again and it ended up just adding the new sheets and not renaming them. That is what I did and I ended up with the exact same .png you posted in your original question:
https://postimg.cc/f3NSyt62

Comment: So how would I got about fixing this issue?

Comment: By the way I add the code to every file that I consolidate. So it's not an excel file that I load info to. I add the code to a new document everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there are many ways of doing what you want.

This is one way: If you want to consider four files at a time for consolidation into one sheet, I would create a master file that contains that code, such as “MergeFilesMaster.xlsm.” Said file would have a sheet which you can name “Control” where you can put a button to activate the code contained in that .xlsm file. Given that your process only contemplates renaming four sheets, I assume you only want to merge four files at a time into a new workbook. The code would thus be:

```
Sub MergeExcelFiles()
    Dim fnameList, fnameCurFile As Variant
    Dim countFiles, countSheets As Integer
    Dim wksCurSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wbkCurBook, wbkSrcBook As Workbook
    Dim a As Long

    fnameList = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", Title:="Choose Excel files to merge", MultiSelect:=True)

    If (vbBoolean <> VarType(fnameList)) Then

        If (UBound(fnameList) > 0) Then
            countFiles = 0
            countSheets = 0

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

            Set wbkCurBook = ActiveWorkbook
            n = wbkCurBook.Name

            For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
                countFiles = countFiles + 1

                Set wbkSrcBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fnameCurFile)

                For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
                    countSheets = countSheets + 1
                    Select Case countSheets
                        Case 1
                            wksCurSheet.Name = "EL"
                        Case 2
                            wksCurSheet.Name = "WL"
                        Case 3
                            wksCurSheet.Name = "FM"
                        Case 4
                            wksCurSheet.Name = "NL"
                    End Select
                    wksCurSheet.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
                Next

                wbkSrcBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
                ' because SaveChanges is set to False, the new names in the original files will not be saved.

            Next

            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

            MsgBox "Processed " & countFiles & " files" & vbCrLf & "Merged " & countSheets & " worksheets", Title:="Merge Excel files"
        End If

    Else
        MsgBox "No files selected", Title:="Merge Excel files"
    End If

    wbkCurBook.Sheets("Control").Delete
    ' delete the empty sheet

    wbkCurBook.SaveAs Filename:= _
            "C:[your directory here]\MergeFilesMaster.xlsx" _
            , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

    ' this will save your MergeFilesMaster.xlsm into an .xlsx file
    ' or add a line to change the file name, such as YYMMDD.xlsx so you can sort them by the date you processed it.

End Sub
```

Let me know if this worked.

Comment: So the only issue with this is that certain files need to be named certain things based on what the excel file is names. i.e. if it has _FM_ in the file name then the page needs to be named FM if it has the name NL in the file name then it needs to be names NL and so on.

Comment: Sorry I just re-ran the program and it worked. I had one of the sheets open that it was trying to add so it errored out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry I take it back it didn't work I just checked the documents it added. even though I manually picked which files to add it pulled info from a different excel files information.

Comment: If you want to name the sheets according to the file names you are consolidating then you need to put the file name you are opening into a variable and then apply that variable value into the sheet.name in the new file. I am not sure what you mean by "it pulled info from a different excel files information." Seems to be a different problem from the one posed on your original question.

Comment: I mean that when I selected the files I wanted to add into one excel file it took the info from another excel file instead of what I chose.

Comment: example I chose to add files with name 071-358-525 but instead it added file name 071-301-107

Comment: This is a problem that is not related to the question you initially posted, which was that more worksheets were generated when you were running your code. The proper way of proceeding would be 1) If any of my answers of comments were useful, please upvote them. 2) initiate a new question and describe the problem you are encountering, so your question is not buried in this thread and you can solicit help from a wider audience.